# Azure Functions cannot create .NET Framework runtime anymore

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

I have a .NET Framework console app that was being deployed on Azure Functions V1 using the .NET Framework runtime.

Trying to redeploy it now, and there's no option for a V1 or .NET framework runtime?

I only see the v2/.NET Core options which won't work for my app.

[These are the choices on .NET runtimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gemd8.png)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it seems that you are unable to create a v1 Function app in Azure Portal, however, you can still get there with a couple of extra steps.

First, create your app choosing `.NET` for the *runtime stack* and `3.1` as the *version*.

Once the app has been created, open the app configuration, switch to the *Function runtime settings* tab and change the *Runtime version* to `~1`

[image]

However, as Jon suggests, v1 apps are likely going to become harder and harder to create so my advice would be to migrate as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looking at the documentation for [Azure Functions runtime versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=csharp%2Cv4), it looks like v1 was the only one to support .NET Framework (aka the Windows desktop framework) rather than .NET Core / .NET.

That's presumably why the v1 description includes:

> Recommended only for C# apps that must use .NET Framework and only supports development in the Azure portal, Azure Stack Hub portal, or locally on Windows computers.

So if your app *must* use .NET Framework as opposed to .NET 5/6 or .NET Core, you'll need to stick to v1. It's not clear where your deployment screenshot comes from, but it sounds like you can create a v3 app in the portal and then downgrade it to v1 *before adding any functions*.

Ultimately though, I would expect keeping deploying on v1 to become trickier and trickier. Eventually I suspect you'll *have* to move off it (although I don't have any idea when that would be) so it's worth coming up with a plan for that sooner rather than later.